# How to configure OpenAds in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

I want to use OpenAds in CakePHP, how can I install it? I put the OpenAds folder in my `vendors` folder and tried to change the URL in the Router but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do a lot more than that.

You should place the OpenAds folder in `/webroot` to start with.
Then you probably want to create a small Helper or Element that can give you the right invocation codes for OpenAds. You should analyse the invocation codes OpenAds gives you and create a Helper that can fill in the blanks like zone ids and so on.